# Pass Javascript Array -> PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

Let's say I have a javascript array with a bunch of elements (anywhere from 50-200).

I want to send that to PHP (prepared statement) using ajax.  Currently, I `.load` a php file many times inside of a loop, but I want to convert that into an array and send the array once, loading the PHP file once instead of 50-200 times.

`array[i] = variable;`

Comment: JSON is your friend :-)

Comment: The quality of advice we can give is limited by the vagueness of your answer. Can you post some sample code of the loop you're using?

Comment: How can I send the data through JSON/retrieve it on the other end?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You could use `JSON.stringify(array)` to encode your array in JavaScript, and then use `$array=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);` in your PHP script to retrieve it.

Comment: don't forget to sanitize your inputs, or you're toast! :D

Comment: You should assume that any input to your PHP scripts could have been compromised by someone with malicious intentions. Run any variables that you are planning to put into a database query through `mysql_real_escape_string()`, and anything that will be put onto the screen through `htmlentities()`

Comment: @Gareth after you use `JSON.stringify(array)`, do you have to insert it into a JSON object literal, like `datavar = { array: array}` ? Or can you just pass `array` in place of `datavar` in the parameter of your .getJSON() request? e.g. `.get(script.php, array, function(data) {...`. Also, is it always `jsondata` within your $_POST ?

Comment: @Gnuey You can either do this: `.get(script.php, JSON.stringify(array), function(data{...` and then retrieve it with `$postvars=file_get_contents('php://input');$array=json_decode($postvars, true);`, or you can use: `.get(script.php, {array: JSON.stringify(array)}, function(data{...` and retrieve it with `$array=json_decode($_POST['array'], true);`.

Comment: Just to make sure, will stringify also work if I have an $array  integers, and in an SQL query I need to match $array (the array of integers) with integers in an attribute column? I read that integers are not specially distinguished, but I just wanted to make sure in this case.

Comment: I think if you want to send dynamic javascript data to php then you can't use this function nor any other function, because then you need to refresh the page in order to make php accept the new data

Comment: the JSON.stringify(array) sent via $.post gets quotes replaced by &quot; so json_decode doesn't work with it unless you do $array=json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['jsondata']));

Answer (score 41):

AJAX requests are no different from GET and POST requests initiated through a `<form>` element. Which means you can use $_GET and $_POST to retrieve the data.

When you're making an AJAX request (jQuery example):

```
// JavaScript file

elements = [1, 2, 9, 15].join(',')
$.post('/test.php', {elements: elements})
```

It's (almost) equivalent to posting this form:

```
<form action="/test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="elements" value="1,2,9,15">
</form>
```

In both cases, on the server side you can read the data from the $_POST variable:

```
// test.php file

$elements = $_POST['elements'];
$elements = explode(',', $elements);
```

For the sake of simplicity I'm joining the elements with comma here. JSON serialization is a more universal solution, though.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't accepted answer as it is exactly what OP asked for and causes less hassle, especially that some frameworks automagically explode POST arrays for you

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function to convert js array or object into a php-compatible array to be sent as http get request parameter:

```
function obj2url(prefix, obj) {
        var args=new Array();
        if(typeof(obj) == 'object'){
            for(var i in obj)
                args[args.length]=any2url(prefix+'['+encodeURIComponent(i)+']', obj[i]);
        }
        else
            args[args.length]=prefix+'='+encodeURIComponent(obj);
        return args.join('&');
    }
```

prefix is a parameter name.

**EDIT:**

```
var a = {
    one: two,
    three: four
};

alert('/script.php?'+obj2url('a', a));
```

Will produce

```
/script.php?a[one]=two&a[three]=four
```

which will allow you to use $_GET['a'] as an array in script.php. You will need to figure your way into your favorite ajax engine on supplying the url to call script.php from js.

Comment: What is any2url?

Answer (score 0):

So use the client-side loop to build a two-dimensional array of your arrays, and send the entire thing to PHP in one request.

Server-side, you'll need to have another loop which does its regular insert/update for each sub-array.

Comment: @Switz I assumed you were using the `data` parameter of a [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call.

Answer (score -1):

You can transfer array from javascript to PHP...

Javascript... ArraySender.html

```
<script language="javascript">

//its your javascript, your array can be multidimensional or associative

plArray = new Array();
plArray[1] = new Array(); plArray[1][0]='Test 1 Data'; plArray[1][1]= 'Test 1'; plArray[1][2]= new Array();
plArray[1][2][0]='Test 1 Data Dets'; plArray[1][2][1]='Test 1 Data Info'; 
plArray[2] = new Array(); plArray[2][0]='Test 2 Data'; plArray[2][1]= 'Test 2';
plArray[3] = new Array(); plArray[3][0]='Test 3 Data'; plArray[3][1]= 'Test 3'; 
plArray[4] = new Array(); plArray[4][0]='Test 4 Data'; plArray[4][1]= 'Test 4'; 
plArray[5] = new Array(); plArray[5]["Data"]='Test 5 Data'; plArray[5]["1sss"]= 'Test 5'; 

function convertJsArr2Php(JsArr){
    var Php = '';
    if (Array.isArray(JsArr)){  
        Php += 'array(';
        for (var i in JsArr){
            Php += '\'' + i + '\' => ' + convertJsArr2Php(JsArr[i]);
            if (JsArr[i] != JsArr[Object.keys(JsArr)[Object.keys(JsArr).length-1]]){
                Php += ', ';
            }
        }
        Php += ')';
        return Php;
    }
    else{
        return '\'' + JsArr + '\'';
    }
}


function ajaxPost(str, plArrayC){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else{xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    xmlhttp.open("POST",str,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('Array=' + plArrayC);
}

ajaxPost('ArrayReader.php',convertJsArr2Php(plArray));
</script>
```

and PHP Code... ArrayReader.php

```
<?php 

eval('$plArray = ' . $_POST['Array'] . ';');
print_r($plArray);

?>
```