# passing Javascript array or object to PHP

Tags: jquery

I have reached here after doing a lot research,
Its simple task creating a lot heck
I am unable to pass javascript array to php
some links which i viewed [1](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/passing-array-data-from-javascript-to-php/37029/3), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625671/passing-javascript-array-to-php-file), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140383/passing-array-from-javascript-to-php-via-post)

I have created javascript object

```
obj={};
```

//for each loop of table to create the key - value pair of object

```
obj[$(r).find('td:eq(2)').html()]=i+1;
```

//end of for each loop

//now I console the object
which shows in console like this
[image: console image of object]

after doing this `var myJSON =JSON.stringify(obj);`

I get the result as empty json string,I want to pass this sting to php via ajax, Not able to figure out why
I have tried creating array as well, need help

[image]

fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/del90/u5gtrs90/1/)
here is full code

```
    $fields_table=$('#datatableRank');
    obj={};
    table.on( 'row-reorder', function ( e, diff, edit ) {

    setTimeout(function() {
    // Update the field order values
    $fields_table.find('tbody').find('tr').each(function(i,r){
            //var element = {};
            //element.id = $(r).find('td:eq(2)').html();
            //element.quantity = i+1;
            //obj.push(i+1);
            //obj1.push($(r).find('td:eq(2)').html());
            $(r).find('td:eq(0)').html(i+1);
            obj[$(r).find('td:eq(2)').html()]=i+1;
        });
    }, 10); // Give it time to load in the DOM
    console.log(obj);
    var myJSON =JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(myJSON);
    }`
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can have a look

Comment: Have you written the AJAX code? It's pretty simple to send JSON over AJAX with jQuery. [See jQuery AJAX docs here.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Presumably `obj` is defined and has the expected value?

Comment: Properties should not begin with a number as they aren't valid in most languages.

Comment: @Yoda i Have declare it as obj={};

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML too. Ideally a jsFiddle showing the issue.

Comment: @yoda here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/del90/u5gtrs90/1/

Comment: now the issue appear only first time after reordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turning out to be another rat in pipe 
everything was perfect only issue was with  setTimeout function()
I had to console the code in settimeout function , now I wrote the ajax code inside the settimeout and thats it
pretty dumb I am

Comment: You found the solution. No problems with that. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can post data to php file ,
jquery [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

like this

```
$.post( "yourfile.php", { data: myJSON })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

then get it from php file "yourfile.php"

```
json_decode($_POST["data"])
```