# sending data from javascript array to php and back

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays, html

i'm trying to work on a design website where users can design something on html5 canvas and than save it on the server. All information is stored on mysql database and the designs are stored in a javascript array. I want to be able to pass copy the entire array from javascript into php, save it in the database and than retrieve it back into javascript.

I've searched the web for this but couldnt find a working solution. Using post/get didnt work. If i print the array using javascript i get something like [object OBJECT, object OBJECT].

Is there anyway to pass arrays between javascript and php?

Thanks

Comment: what is the code that you have written

Comment: Googling a sentence verbatim from your question, *Is there anyway to pass arrays between javascript and php?* returns this as the top result: "How can I pass a variable from JavaScript to PHP" http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.javascript-variable

Comment: Yes but you cannot pass from Javascript to PHP.

Comment: @flov You cannot pass them directly, but there are means to do so. Your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @izuriel I was answering the preceding comment which only provides a way to pass from PHP to javascript.

Comment: @flov I know. You can pass data from Javascript to PHP, and you can pass data from PHP to Javascript. There are means and methods to do so. I've done them and I do them daily, your comment is incorrect.

Comment: i searched properly but didnt find good examples or tutorials on it. I dont have code because i'm asking how to achieve it. looks like stackoverflow is starting to fill up with too many overjudging people who keep expecting code hence the negative reputation. I mean if i asked a question on how to setup a particular compiler for a particular problem what code would there be to display?

Comment: web code isnt strict so theres no point in showing code. I mean even if i had code like var myarray[]
with method of storing coordinates or even methods like function draw(parameters){// add properties to my stuff than store in box array} would still be useless due to the structure of web programming and totally irrelevant to my question. In the last few months everytime i asked a question in the last i got negative rep. I'm not dumb in searching properly and trying first. What has happened to stackoverflow? :( It used to be good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by using AJAX. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29.

jQuery can help with that http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: do you have any good links for AJAX? I've tried JSON and it doesnt work. I'll try JQuery and get back to you on it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, That may help  [Pass JS Array to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035547/pass-javascript-array-php).

A suggestion: Try to search stackoverflow before posting, it can save alot of time.

Comment: i tried that already before posting this question and it didnt work for me