# Javascript POST not working - Sending Javascript array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I know there a fair few entries on SO and the web on this however I just can't get to work - any help would be appreciated.

So i have an array in Javascript which I'm trying to pass on to PHP.

I've got a little JS function to first POST it, so:

```
function sendToPHP() {
$.post("index.php", { "variable": toSearchArray });
}
```

Then down the page, I have the PHP:

```
<?php 
    $myval = $_POST['variable'];
    print_r ($myval);
    ?>
```

*The prints just there for me to check.

Any ideas - fyi I'm using MAMP so its localhost:8888/index.php. Could this be causing issues in that the URL is not correct?

Thanks.

Comment: what does the print_r output?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the results of the AJAX post so I don't know why you would expect to see anything

Comment: Actually I just realized, are you sending the data through ajax to the same page you are on? ajax doesn't work like that. You would usually send the ajax data to another page and add a 3rd argument to $.post, a callback function, that gets called when the ajax call is done and gets passed in the output from the ajax call. Inside that callback is where you would update the screen.

Comment: The output gives nothing.
So with the AJAX post what needs to be done - I assumed its just handed over?

Comment: Try 

$.post({url:"index.php", data:{ "variable": toSearchArray }});

Comment: @Ramesh That doesn't match the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) API at all

Comment: Refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax

Answer (score 3):

You have a misunderstanding about how ajax works. Although jquery makes it easy, it is still not automatic. You should just find a tutorial about ajax with jquery, but if you want to just send an array to php and see the output on screen, something like this would work:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //attach to the button a click event
    $('#btn').click(function(){
            //get the value from the textbox
        var txt=$('#txt').val();
            //if txt is blank, alert an error
        if(txt == ''){
            alert("Enter some text");
        } else {
                    //send txt to the server
                    //notice the function at the end. this gets called after the data has been sent
            $.post('catcher.php', {'text':txt}, function(data){
                            //now data is an object, so put the message in the div
                $('#response').text(data.message);
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" id="btn">
<pre id="response" style="overflow:auto;width:800px;height:600px;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid black;">&nbsp;</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

catcher.php:

```
<?php
//if something was posted
if(!empty($_POST)){
    //start an output var
    $output = array();

    //do any processing here.
    $output['message'] = "Success!";

    //send the output back to the client
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

It is better to use 2 files, one for the user to load that initiates the ajax call and one page to handle the ajax call. Sending an array works the same, just replace getting the textbox value with sending an array.

Comment: Hi - Ok i see this working however as I have 2 files - I how do i get it back to the array value to teh original i.e. index.php - shall i just use sessions?

Comment: it is already an array in index.php. However if you want a response from the server (file 2, catcher.php) to be an array, you can specify a data type in your post, most likely 'json', as the fourth argument. Then anything sent from the second file you can just run through json_encode in php and the callback function will get that. I'll update the example to show this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you open your page (`index.php`)

1. A `GET` request is issued to `index.php` and the content is returned. There are **no** values in the `$_POST` array so your `print_r()` line does nothing.
2. Javascript is executed that sends a `POST` request to `index.php` via AJAX. Note that this is an entirely new request, separate to the original `GET`. The `$_POST` array will be populated on *this* request however the response is discarded.

Hopefully this will illustrate what you *can* do.

##### ajax.php

```php
<?php
header("content-type: application/json");
exit(json_encode($_POST));
```

##### index.php

```html
<script>
const toSearchArray = ['some', 'array', 'with', 'values'];
$.post('ajax.php', {
  variable: toSearchArray
}).done(data => {
  console.log(data) // here you will see the result of the ajax.php script
})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi - Ok i see this working however as I have 2 files - I how do i get it back to the array value to teh original i.e. index.php - shall i just use sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring variable toSearchArray as array. consider it an javascript object.
var toSearchArray = {}.

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't think thats the right way to do it when it comes to arrays, see you need to use JSON encode in javascript then JSON decode in php 
Refer to this question [Pass Javascript Array -> PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035547/pass-javascript-array-php)

Comment: In jquery, you can pass an object and jquery will serialize it to a valid post payload. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I'm sooo lost. Literally no idea why what I have is not working
What do i need to read up?
All I want to do is send a javascript array to PHP