# How to pass Javascript array to PHP file using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have to pass a Javascript arry to a PHP file while AJAX call.

Below is my js array:

```
var myArray = new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");
```

This JS code has to pass JS array to PHP file using AJAX request and will show count of array.

```
function ProcessAJAXRequest()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphpfile.php",
        data: {"id" : 1, "myJSArray" : myArray},
        success: function (data) 
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This myphpfile.php file has to return the count of the array

```
<?php 
    $myPHPArray = $_POST["myJSArray"];
    echo count($myPHPArray);
 ?>
```

There is error in PHP file. I am getting undefined index: myPHPArray. How should acheive my required functionality?

Comment: Why not to calculate the count on client side ?

Comment: i dont see that var in your function scope.

Comment: your code is perfectly fine. I am getting count 3 without any change. I am not getting any error. using PHP 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert js array in json format by `JSON.stringify`

```
function ProcessAJAXRequest()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphpfile.php",
        data: {"id" : 1, "myJSArray" : JSON.stringify(myArray)},
        success: function (data) 
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And In the `PHP` use `json_decode` function to get value in array

```
json_decode($_POST["myJSArray"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to converts a value to JSON and send it to server.

```
data: JSON.stringify({"id" : 1, "myJSArray" : myArray})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JSON.stringify(array)` to encode your array in JavaScript, and then use

`$array=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);`

in your PHP script to retrieve it.please check this link

[Pass Javascript Array -> PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035547/pass-javascript-array-php)

Answer (score 0):

What seems to me is that your array is not available in the function scope:

```
function ProcessAJAXRequest(){
   var myArray = new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW"); // this has to be in fn scope
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myphpfile.php",
      data: {"id" : 1, "myJSArray" : JSON.stringify(myArray)},  // do the stringify before posting
      success: function (data){
         alert(data);
      }
   });
}
```