# variable is not passing from javascript to php through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a code that should pass the value of all checked list to a php file , so as to delete the rows of a csv file . so the check box value is dynamic

```
<tr><td><span class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox"'+count+'" name="options[]" value="'+count+'"><label for="checkbox1"></label></span></td>';
```

and i have to get all the value of checked checkbox , so i used javascript  and this javascript will pass the value to PHP through ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".button1" ).click(function() {
            var val = [];
            $("input:checked").each(function (index,value) {
                    val[index] = this.value;
            });

            var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(val);
            $.ajax({
                data: {'kvcArray': myJSONText},
                url: 'Index.php',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    // alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

so it has to pass the value to same page (Index.php) and PHP code is'

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['kvcArray'])) {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects' );</script>";
        var_dump(json_decode($_POST['kvcArray'], true));
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
    }
?>
```

but it is not posting the value . till Javascript code everything works fine ( i did an alert to check the data is fetched or not ) but the value is not getting posted in PHP ,

Comment: You are not returning any value from php

Comment: i didn't get you @MrKhan

Comment: var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(val); console.log val before this line and check if it contains value.

Comment: yes it has , i checked it before till there it is working properly @MrKhan

Comment: Ok next in php before if condition echo $_POST and check.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: myJSONText in C:\xampp\htdocs\NewOne\Index.php on line 343 gives me an error @MrKhan

Comment: Use print_r since its an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223799/discussion-between-niranjana-neeranj-and-mr-khan).

Comment: Why are you re-posting this? Also here your code is changed and now is the answer from your previous question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass Javascript array to PHP using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574758/pass-javascript-array-to-php-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was with the checkboxes set. Nonetheless, its working now. All the values being checked are passes properly and can be checked by uncommenting the lines in php code.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <span class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options1[]">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="options2[]">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="options3[]">
        <label for="checkbox1"></label>
    </span>
    <button class="button1">Submit</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".button1" ).click(function() {
            var val = [];

            //Fetch all checked values 
            $("input:checked").each(function (index,value) {
                val[index] = this.value;
            });
            
             
            var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(val);
            $.ajax({
                data: {'kvcArray': myJSONText},
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    //To Test the incoming values just uncomment these lines below.
    // print_r($_POST);
    // die();

    /*Check if form value is set*/ 
    if (isset($_POST['kvcArray'])) {
        // Pass the value to ajax success method
        echo $_POST['kvcArray'];
        die();
    }
    /*-------------------------*/ 
?>
```

Comment: This is not a valid html !