# send Array using Ajax from javascript to php, no using form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, post

im trying to send a array from javascript to php using ajax. My problem is that array in PHP is empty and i dont know why.

My array: vacio['num1:1','num2:2'....]

this my javasvascript:

```
    var vacio = new Array; 
    vacio = addElementAttributesToArrayEncode();

    var miJSON = JSON.stringify(vacio);

    var miAjax = new Request({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/multyWeb/actions/maintenance/mUpdateProductAction.php",
        data: "ark=" + miJSON,
         onSuccess: function(textoRespuesta){
        console.log("ok");console.log(textoRespuesta);
        },
        onFailure: function(){
        console.log("fallo");
        }
})
miAjax.send();
```

And this is my php:

```
if($_POST){
        echo "recibo algo POST Producto";
        //recibo los datos y los decodifico con PHP
        $str = json_decode($_POST['ark'], true); 
        echo json_encode($str); }

        else { echo "Error del POST";}
```

And the array $str is empty... what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035547/pass-javascript-array-php

Answer (score 2):

modify your ajax call and set the content type to json and send the data as json instead of stringify it.

```
var miAjax = new Request({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/multyWeb/actions/maintenance/mUpdateProductAction.php",
    contentType: "application/json"
    data: {'data':miJSON},
     onSuccess: function(textoRespuesta){
    console.log("ok");console.log(textoRespuesta);
    },
    onFailure: function(){
    console.log("fallo");
    }
})
miAjax.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be used in the first example jQuery

```
$.post('/multyWeb/actions/maintenance/mUpdateProductAction.php', {'param':'value','param1':'value1'}, function(data){
    return;
});
```

OR

```
var vacio = new Array; 
vacio = addElementAttributesToArrayEncode();

var miJSON = JSON.stringify(vacio);

var miAjax = new Request({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/multyWeb/actions/maintenance/mUpdateProductAction.php",
    data: {'ark':miJSON},
     onSuccess: function(textoRespuesta){
    console.log("ok");console.log(textoRespuesta);
    },
    onFailure: function(){
    console.log("fallo");
    }
})
miAjax.send();
```