# How can I pass an array from JS to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, parameter-passing

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#csv_export', function () {

        // I need to pass this array to where the form below submits
        var arr = ['item1', 'item2'];

        $('<form action="csv_export/person?filename=export.csv" method="POST"/>')
        .append($('{!! csrf_field() !!}<input type="hidden" name="type" value="save">'))
        .appendTo($(document.body)) //it has to be added somewhere into the <body>
        .submit();
    });
```

As I've commented in my code, there is `arr` that I need to pass it to that page the form points out. How can I do that?

---

Noted that I can putting this in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="arr" value="'+arr+'">
```

But I it has two problems:

1. character length limitation
2. the result will be a string. *(while I need an array in the server side)*

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Javascript Array -> PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035547/pass-javascript-array-php)

Comment: @hassan I passed it by setting it as the value of a hidden input. But in this case, there is character length limitation.

Comment: please mention that in your question then, your issue is not in passing javascript array to php, it's in the limitation , right?

Comment: hint:  you are not doing anything with `res` and are submitting a hard coded value

Comment: The limit on `POST` parameters should be very high. How big is the array?

Comment: @Barmar Maybe 1M (milion) characters

Comment: Can you use AJAX instead of constructing a form to submit?

Comment: @Barmar Actually I did it first. But it didn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the array to JSON with `JSON.stringify()`. And instead of constructing the input as a string, use a jQuery function to do it:

```
$('<form action="csv_export/person?filename=export.csv" method="POST"/>')
    .append($('{!! csrf_field() !!}'))
    .append($("<input>", {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'arr',
        value: JSON.stringify(arr)
    });
).appendTo('body')
.submit();
```

In the PHP script, use `json_decode($_POST['arr'], true)` to get the array.

You should also be able to use AJAX:

```
$.post('csv_export/person?filename=export.csv', { arr: JSON.stringify(arr) });
```

For a small array, you could just use `{ arr: arr }` and then access `$_POST['arr']` as an array. But when you pass an array like this, each element becomes a separate post parameter, and by default PHP only allows 1000 parameters. You can change this in `php.ini`, but using JSON is probably a simpler solution for this case.

Comment: Ok, I got the result on the server side. Just the result is a string structured as JSON. Can I get it as an array on the server side?

Comment: Got it .. this works as well for me: `(array) json_decode($_POST['arr'], true)`

Comment: You don't need `(array)`, `json_decode()` should return an array.