# send array of strings from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have in Javascript my array and ajax call:

```
righe = [];
righe.push({
  ragione_sociale:  $('#ragione_sociale').val(),
  via:                      $('#via').val(),
  cap:                  $('#cap').val(),
  localita:             $('#localita').val(),
  provincia:            $('#provincia').val(),
  telefono:         $('#telefono').val(),
  fax:          $('#fax').val(),
  settore:          $('#settore').val(),
  attivita:         $('#attivita').val(),
  note:         $('#note').val()
 });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajaxcall/inserisciAzienda.php",
      data: {righe : righe},
  success: function(data){

            console.log("okkk "+data);

    }......
```

and this is my inserisciAzienda.php:

```
<?php

  $dati = array ($_POST["righe"]);

  echo "result: ".$dati[0];
```

?>

but I have the following error:

```
 okkk <br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b> /Applications/
 XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/badges/ajaxcall/inserisciAzienda.php</b> 
 on line <b>11</b><br />result: Array
```

I'm not able to get the array on the php file.

Comment: What do you get when you do `print_r($dati[0]);` instead?

Comment: `$dati[0]` (which is really just `$_POST["righe"]`) is an array.  What exactly are you trying to do?  What do you expect/want the result to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Javascript Array -> PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035547/pass-javascript-array-php)

Comment: I am sure you need to serialize your array at the time of passing

Comment: try   echo "result: ".$dati[0]['ragione_sociale'];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: I have to extract received data and send them to a c# web service like this: [WebMethod]
    public bool ScriviAziende(string ragione_sociale,  string via, string cap, string localita, string provincia, string telefono, string fax, string settore, string attivita, string note)

Answer (score 0):

`echo` can't print non-scalar variables (objects, arrays). This can be done with [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). With your code:

```
$dati = array ($_POST["righe"]);

echo "result: ";
print_r($dati[0]);
```

Comment: I have to extract received data and send them to a c# web service like this: [WebMethod] public bool ScriviAziende(string ragione_sociale, string via, string cap, string localita, string provincia, string telefono, string fax, string settore, string attivita, string note). So i have get the strings.

Comment: Getting settings isn't the same as printing them. Do you know how to get values from an array?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I solved with

```
$dati = $_POST["righe"];
```

instead

```
$dati = array($_POST["righe"]);
```

and getting values in this way:

```
echo $dati[0]['ragione_sociale'];
```