# Convert HTML element to array on same name in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have two divs that have the same purpose but different values

```
<div id="tracks-1">
     <div>
        <label>Song Title</label>
         <input type="text" name="tracks[song_title]" value="">
         <input type="text" name="tracks[price]" value="">

     </div>
</div>

<div id="tracks-2">
     <div>
        <label>Song Title</label>
         <input type="text" name="tracks[song_title]" value="">
         <input type="text" name="tracks[price]" value="">
     </div>
</div>
```

when I submit it via post request Laravel I get the tracks data something like this

```
"tracks" => [
    "song_title" => "some title",
    "price" => "23"
    "song_title" => "some title 2",
    "price" => "25"
]
```

I want it Like this

```
"tracks" => [
   0 => ["song_title" => "some title", "price" => "23"],
   1 => ["song_title" => "some title 2", "price" => "25"]
]
```

Is there a way to do without javascript and JQuery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5035796/10634638

Comment: how your controller looks like?

Comment: You need to add one more array into the input name array like this - `name="tracks[][song_title]"`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `song_title` reference from the name attributes in the form inputs to get an integer-indexed array...

```
<div id="tracks-1">
    <div>
        <label>Song Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="tracks[]" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tracks-2">
    <div>
        <label>Song Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="tracks[]" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could use an array map on the posted form data like this in your post controller...

```
$tracks = array_map(function($trackTitle) {
    return ["song_title" => $trackTitle];
}, $_POST['tracks']);
```

Comment: Don't mutate POST values. Store into a variable instead.

Comment: What if there are more input fields then?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like :

```
if $q = 1" { echo "song title }
```